# ASP MVC HTML form POST List<Entity>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, post, reference, viewmodel

Today I have been struggling with the same problem all day. I am still ASP MVC beginner, coming from the Flex world. But now I am working on some ASP MVC project.

I think this is a quite complex problem, therefore I am trying to describe the problem very detailed. So thank you in advance, that you are talking the time to go through this!

**System description:**

I am trying to build a "ProjectManagementSystem". You can have multiple projects, where each project has a name and a description. A project also has a list off additional details. A normal form would let me enter name and description for a new project, right?

Now, the requirement is, that additional form elements can be added. For example I want to add a new input which will let me enter the available budget for **all** existing and new projects.

The budget is an additional project detail. IE. when the a from element for the budget is added, a new project detail is added to all projects.

**Classes:**

I got the class "Project" which has a list of "ProjectDetails" and it also provides some interface to get, add and delete a "ProjectDetail" from the "Project":

```
public class Project : ProjectItem
{
    public virtual IList<ProjectDetail> Details { get; set; }

    public Project(string name, string description) : base(name, description)
    {
        Details = new List<ProjectDetail>();
    }

    public Project()
        : this("new project", "this is a new project")
    { 

    }

    public virtual void AddDetail(string name)
    {
        var detail = GetDetail(name);

        if (detail == null)
        {
            detail = new ProjectDetail(name, "empty");
            detail.Project = this;
            Details.Add(detail);
        }
    }

    public virtual void RemoveDetail(string name)
    {
        var detail = GetDetail(name);

        if (detail != null)
        {
            detail.Project = null;
            Details.Remove(detail);
        }
    }

    public virtual ProjectDetail GetDetail(string name)
    {
        ProjectDetail result = null;

        foreach (ProjectDetail detail in Details)
        {
            if (detail.Name.Equals(name))
            {
                result = detail;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The "ProjectDetail" class looks like this:

```
public class ProjectDetail : ProjectItemDetail
{
    [NotNull]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public ProjectDetail(string name, string value)
        : base(name, value)
    { 

    }

    public ProjectDetail()
        : this("new project detail", "empty")
    { 

    }
}
```

Note, that "ProjectDetail" inherits Name and Value from "ProjectItem" base class.

I am trying to create view, that will let me edit the single Value property of all "ProjectDetails" in the Details list of a particular "Project".
Now, each "ProjectDetail" is related to a "FormElement" and they are matched by their Name property.

```
public class FormElement
{
    public static string TYPE_UNKNOWN   = "typeUnknown";
    public static string TYPE_NUMERIC   = "typeNumeric";
    public static string TYPE_CHAR      = "typeChar";
    public static string TYPE_DATE      = "typeDate";

    [NotNull]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public virtual int Position { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }

    public FormElement(string name, int position, string type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Position = position;
        Type = type;
    }

    public FormElement()
        : this("unknownFormElement", -1, TYPE_UNKNOWN)
    {

    }

}
```

And the "Form" class:

```
public class Form : Entity
{
    [NotNull]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<FormElement> FormElements { get; set; }

    public Form(string name)
    {
        Name = name;

        FormElements = new List<FormElement>();
    }

    public Form()
        : this("unknownWebform")
    { 

    }

    //public interface for getting, adding, deleting FormElement 
}
```

So, the view will need to render the "Form" and fill the elements with the value of the related "ProjectDetail".

So, the view gets passed in a "ProjectEditModel":

```
public class ProjectEditModel
{
    public Form Form;

    public Project Project;

    public ProjectViewModel() {}
}
```

The following view is strongly typed to "ProjectEditModel":

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
   {%>

        <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit Project</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.Name) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project.Name)%>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.Description)%>
            </div>
             <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project.Description)%>
            </div>

            <% 

                foreach (var formElement in Model.Form.FormElements)
                {   
                    if (formElement.Type.Equals(Domain.Model.FormElement.TYPE_CHAR))
                    { 
                    %>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            <%: Html.Label(Model.Project.GetDetail(formElement.Name).Name)%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project.GetDetail(formElement.Name).Value)%>
                        </div>
                    <%
                    }
                    if (formElement.Type.Equals(Domain.Model.FormElement.TYPE_NUMERIC))
                    {

                    }
                }

            %>

            <p>
                <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<%: Model.Project.Id %>" />
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>

        </fieldset>
    </div>

<% } %>
```

This will render correctly and show a form element for every additional detail. But when I do POST back the model, the constructor will have been invoked and this way I loose all my references. PENG!

I have read, that MVC "just works" like this and I am willing to accept that, but how do I solve my problem then? You need anymore information?

Thanks very much, would really appreciate help!

Comment: Can you tell what are you expecting to get at the server's side after postback? I'm not really get your " the constructor will have been invoked and this way I loose all my references". What's the constructor you are talking about ?
Also, can you show your controller action code ?

Comment: Hi Andrey, what I mean is that the constructor of the view model is called, so all information (references) will get lost. The POST action method in the controller will get passed a new instance of the view model. It´s not that important to know how it looks like. If I don´t create a new "Project" in the view model constructor, the references to the "Project" will be even null. I made sure the properties of the view model were correctly populated when I passed it to the view in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

MVC won't automatically handle the way you are trying to dynamically create the form. It won't bind your collection of form elements to the collection as it has no way of distinguishing between them.

Try the methodology described in [this blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) to handle dynamic collection rendering and model binding.